# .next jQuery not working - need to toggle multiple divs

Tags: jquery

I need to toggle some divs slide down and such and have been looking at stack overflow and most posts point to using the .next function, when I implement this nothing seems to happen.

My jQuery is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".product_slidedown").click(function(){
            $(".slide_details").next('div.product_slidedown').slideToggle();
            });
        });
```

and the HTML is

```
<div class="product_slidedown" id="1">
        <div class="item_details_heading">
            Product Description
        </div>
        <div class="slide_details"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product_slidedown" id="2">
        <div class="item_details_heading">
            Product Dimensions
        </div>
        <div class="slide_details"></div>
    </div>
```

jsFiddle over at http://jsfiddle.net/RxDcK/

If I take out the .next function it works but slides down both divs.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Documentation FTW: http://api.jquery.com/next/. Also you don't clearly explain what you would like the code to do. Should the `.slide_details` element inside the clicked `.product_slidedown` be opened/closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe this is what you are looking for, try:

http://jsfiddle.net/RxDcK/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".product_slidedown").click(function () {
        $(this).find(".slide_details").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

with the above code, you are finding the `.slide_details` div within the `.product_slidedown` div that you clicked within.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're calling `.next` on the top-most div, `#2`. `.slide_details` is a child of `div.product_slidedown`, so calling next isn't going to return anything.

Change your click binding to:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item_details_heading").click(function(){           
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".product_slidedown .item_details_heading").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".slide_details").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EZnUP/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the recommended `on()` method instead as well... as shown here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamdehaven/V85q9/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".product_slidedown").on('click', function () {
        $(this).find(".slide_details").slideToggle();
    });
});
```